# Project Tango does not recognize the USB connection

Tags: connection, usb, project, tango

I have a Project Tango device and I want to connect to my computer through USB connection to work with the device, I already enable the USB debugging in the DEVELOPER OPTIONS, my computer it's a MACBOOK with YOSEMITE OS and when I plug the cable in both devices does not happen anything, not even like MEDIA DEVICE (MTP) connection, I change the USB cable for another and occurs the same thing, I try to make the connection with another computer with different OS and obtain the same result; **by the way, when I plug the USB cable in the Project Tango device the battery icon change to the charge icon**

Anyone knows what's happen?

Regards

Comment: I sent an email to "Project Tango Help" to explain the situation and they gonna issue a replacement of my project tango device.